# Error when trying to get-iam-policy gcloud

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-iam

I'm trying to get an IAM policy from some specific list of projects in CSV file using this bash script:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "Getting IAM list from accounts:"
sleep 4
while read -r projectId || [ -n $projectId ] 
do
gcloud projects get-iam-policy ${projectId}
echo $projectId
done < NonBillingAccountGCP.csv
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.projects.get-iam-policy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument.
<project-ID-from-csv>
```

If I'm running this script using the project-id it does work and print all IAM policies.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: check the content of your CSV file! does it contains "project-name"?

Comment: Its do print the projects names from the CSV file as expected.
Thanks!

Comment: are you using project names or projects ids/numbers?

Comment: I'm using Project ID's

Comment: Is it a file format issue, where there's an (invisible) carriage return at the end of the line(s)?

Comment: Check if the file is formatted as Linux and not as DOS. That affects the line termination characters. VI will tell you the format and can change it. Use the VI **ff* command.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley that's was the issue. I converted the CSV file to UNIX and it's worked!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the error results from the first line heading (`PROJECT_ID` or similar) in your CSV.

You can use `awk` to drop the first line and for a slightly cleaner variant:

```sh
FILE="NonBillingAccountGCP.cs"
PROJECTS=$(awk "NR>1" ${FILE})
for PROJECT in ${PROJECTS}
do
  echo ${PROJECT}
  gcloud projects get-iam-policy ${PROJECT}
done
```

This format also allows you to compose `gcloud projects list`:

```sh
PROJECTS=$(gcloud projects list \
--filter=... \
--format="value(projectId)")
```

Comment: Thanks for that! The issue was with the CSV format (DOS instead of Unix).